# Kolmogorov axioms proof in discrete space

Tags: probability

In a book (high school book), I read that Kolmogorov axioms can be proven in discrete sample spaces.

Can anyone prove them?

> 1. $0\leq P(A) \leq 1$ ($A\subseteq S)$
> 2. $P(S) = 1$ (S is universal set)
> 3. If $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$

Comment: Strange question... axioms are "free truths". Why do you need to prove them? Moreover, what does mean "discrete sample space"? Is it finite? Is it infinite? Please, be more precise.

Comment: A strange statement.  They probably mean that if $P$ is a nonnegative function on a finite set $S$ with sum $1$, then additivity follows (additivity means $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ for $A, B$ disjoint), simply because we define $P(A) = \sum_{a \in A} P(a)$.  This additivity is precisely property 3.

In the general case (infinite $S$), the probability function $P$ is not defined on each individual element of $S$, but is rather constructed as a *measure*.  Property 3 is then not a consequence of the other axioms, but has to be assumed as one of them.

Comment: @the_candyman . Yes I mean finite. English is not my native language and I don't know the right English name of some of mathematical concepts. I mean a set like {1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 , ... , 10}.

Comment: ok, but I was trying to pointing out that you can "verify" the axioms using the intuitive definition of probability. You can't "prove" them, otherwise they aren't axioms.

Comment: @the_candyman , The book I read said they are axioms for infinite spaces but It also said they are theorems that can be proven in finite sample spaces (and it is some of the book exercises!) The book is not available in English so quoting the exact sentence of book is useless.